# lost some rep after I hit realc on the reputation audit

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-audit

So till today morning I had 1148 rep. I accepted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900525/web-matrix-does-not-let-me-upload-all-my-files-to-a-new-ftp-cannot-upload-all-fi) and got 1150.

I did notice It went mysterious up since a few days ago, I assumed it was from a few edits I made to a few questions (note I don't have edit privilege)

So I just went to stackoverflow.com/reputation later this morning and saw the bottom it said my rep is **1136** ? So without thinking what it does I hit the *"Trigger Reputation Recalc"* button, and a few hours later, now, I see my rep has gone down to 1136 =(

The last +2 I got as seen on stackoverflow.com/reputation is dated today which I assume if from accepting that earlier mentioned answer?

I'd just like to know what happened? (Also as a side Question, do good edits get +2? I made an edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908147/what-does-it-mean-to-say-wpf-has-the-dispatcher-class) and it shows a +2 on my rep graph)

Thanks

Comment: This is normal: The recalc withdraws reputation from deleted answers, answers to since deleted questions, upvotes from since deleted user accounts, etc.

Comment: oh you shoulda put that as an answer, oh didn't realize deleted questions loose rep. No way to know which questions there were right?

Comment: That could also relate to some combination of having a previously accepted answer *unaccepted* (maybe someone posted something better recently), and some posts you've previously downvoted being deleted.

Comment: the answer is yes for rep for good edits, (to a maximum of 1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you for instance deleted any of your upvoted answers, or if any question (of which you had provided an upvoted answer on) got deleted, the reputation from that answer will be removed upon recalculation.

I suspect, though I can't find a reference for it, that if you deleted some *downvoted* answer, your reputation will be bumped up on next recalc.

---

You can see your total *actual* reputation at the bottom of stackoverflow.com/reputation.

Mine says

> ** total rep 31472 :)

even though the header on stackoverflow.com says 31,891

Comment: The short of it is that you can't get or lose rep from posts that no longer exist